# Service did not start due to a logon failure

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, services, credentials

My company installs and supports a third party print management software for our customers. The software requires administrative level privileges for printer/print job manipulation. To do this the service uses a "Log On As" scheme, where we give the service an admin username/password to Run As. This works great 99% of the time. I've recently run into an issue where it has failed in a very odd way.

Given a username/password for an admin, the service will start, run, and be happy. After a power cycle (sometimes) it will fail to start with the error "Service did not start due to a logon failure". If I go in and look, it has the user/password filled in, and if I manually try to start it I am presented with the same error. However, if I retype the password and start it, it works!

I can reboot the machine multiple times, and it starts up just fine. However every now and then (like the other day with a power outtage) the PC starts up and fails to start the service. It makes you open the service properties and retype THE SAME password and it will then run. As can be expected this is not ideal behavior.

I've tried setting up a new user account, and changing passwords globally, but nothing seems to prevent the issue from cropping up.

I've never seen this happen in any other install. Now I know my software/service is NOT able to change credentials/permissions so to me it has to be something windows or domain based. It is indeed running on a domain, and it's running Windows 10. I know Windows 10 has these online sync accounts and stuff, and I'm not sure if this can be causing an issue like this or not? I'm not very acclimated to the nuances of Windows 10 yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[Update]**

So I understand it's very easy to say "It's the software". The issue is it's been used for over a decade, without any issues related to this, and this is a single site that is experiencing the issue. So I have to take a leap of faith and look at avenues outside of that simple explanation. An easy one would be DeepFreeze type software, unfortunately there's nothing like it running.

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with third-party software itself.  Use the free Windows 7 VMs that Microsoft offers, add the Windows 7 VM to the domain, install the third-party service.  Duplicate the behavior on previous versions of Windows, then go to the third-party, with your data and request they fix the behavior within their software.

Comment: How would it be the third party service causing a windows logon failure? It uses the credentials typed into the service's properties window? Like any other Windows service. The service/software have no rights to change these credentials in the properties, or in Windows, and can't touch permissions. It just USES those credentials to try to gain privileges....

Comment: Just to clarify, the software does not misbehave, the service fails to start at all because the logon credentials it was given fail to be authenticated through windows. The credentials are given to the service THROUGH windows, the service is started BY windows, and the the credentials are rejected BY windows. The software has nothing to do with any of those steps.

Comment: The service itself determines if it was the authenication event was a sucess or failure based on the response it gets.  If its not passing the correct infomation then of course it will fail when that happens.

Comment: The information is correct? I input the same user/pass everytime it fails, and it starts working again. The credentials never change.

Comment: Just because the information was inputed correctly does not mean the information the service is using is correct.  The fact that you can repeat the behavior, by allowing it to fail then "entering the information again" indicates a problem with the service itself, not the scheduled task.

Comment: So you think the service is corrupting that data on reboot? Then whenever I try to restart without changing the input information it's still corrupted, then when I manually input it again it grabs the new (clean) data and uses it? Launches only to be corrupted again, and repeat? If that's the case do you have any troubleshooting or debugging tips?

Comment: I am just saying it sounds like the service is not getting the authentication details from the task.

Comment: Does the issue occur on a clean shutdown/reboot? Or only where the system has lost power or user has just powered off without shutting down the OS? You could use SysInternals Process Monitor to monitor the boot process to see what is happening and compare a 'good' start with a failed startup of  the service. From the description it implies that somehow the stored password associated with the service is somehow being changed.

Comment: Couldn't you just make the software run as NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM? (aka the system user) that way, a username/password is not even needed.

Comment: I'm unclear how to do a password-less logon with any user in the log on tab of a services properties. If your talking about not specifying a user and simply run as local account, that gives various permission issues.

Comment: I indeed mean that. Any service that requires network login credentials is bound to run in problems like these.

Comment: I've had issues with permissions before, but the fact that you can input the password, and eventually have it fail, only to input the same password.... that is completely new to me and everyone who's installed/maintained the software over the past decade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long overdue, but figured I should answer my own question.

It was indeed windows/domain based issue. Once they finally excluded it from the domain use policy, it hasn't failed again.

Comment: I recently got this problem too. Yes, it's domain policy issue, but did you find a way to like write a script to check if the service is running and automatically retype the password. If it's stopped?